# How to view Missed calls log while talking?

Tags: 7.5

I want to view the missed call log as I am talking to another person. I am not talking about receiving the call while I am talking. But the call I already received, and want to say that number to the person now I am talking with.

I try to enter into the phone, it takes me to the current calling screen. It doesnt take me to the missed call, received call log....

Is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

Windows Button > Phone section (which re-opens the call) > Press the back button. This should show the call history.

Comment: Excellent.. how did you find it?